# UWP Application launched with LaunchUriAsync is not showing main page

Tags: uwp

I have launched a uwp app with LaunchUriAsync but the application is not loading the properly(not showing main page of the application), it is showing default blue screen

```
 public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            callUri();


        }

        private async void callUri()
        {
            var uriBing = new Uri((@"testapptolaunch://"));

            // Launch the URI
            var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriBing);

        }
```

and in app.xaml.cs added the below code

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
            {
                ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
                // Navigate to a view 
                Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
                if (rootFrame == null)
                {
                    rootFrame = new Frame();
                    Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
                }
                // assuming you wanna go to MainPage when activated via protocol
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), eventArgs);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Hi @Sruthi A if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> but the application is not loading the properly(not showing main page of the application), it is showing default blue screen

The problem is you have not invoke  [`Window.Current.Activate();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.window.activate#Windows_UI_Xaml_Window_Activate) method in `OnActivated` override function. Please use the following to replace yours.

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{

    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
    {
        ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
        // Navigate to a view 
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }
        // assuming you wanna go to MainPage when activated via protocol
        rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), eventArgs);

    }
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```