# LaunchUriAsync call from a Windows Service does not launch the UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-services, url-scheme

I made a windows service that should launch a UWP app from a certain event. The approach I did is via the Protocol extension of the UWP app. I read about that approach [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ca6aa6a2-cd51-4dc2-ad49-b21bb797af77/uwpxaml-how-to-start-an-uwp-app-through-windows-service-?forum=wpdevelop)

I have verified that the uri is working by typing the uri string into the explorer address bar (i.e. "myapp:" , "myapp://test"), but when i tried these into the windows service, I get a success return value, but the UWP app was never launched.

My function for calling goes like this:

```cs
    async private void LaunchApp()
    {
            WriteToFile("Launchapp function");

            try
            {
                uri = new Uri(@"myapp://test");
                WriteToFile("URI created");
                var success = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);

                if (success)
                {
                    WriteToFile("URI Launched");
                }
                else
                {
                    WriteToFile("URI Launch Failed");
                }
            }catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                WriteToFile("ANE exception");
            }
            catch (UriFormatException ufe)
            {
                WriteToFile("UFE exception");
            }
    }
```

I'm worried that the LaunchUriAsync API may not be able to see the package due to separation of the service from the user desktop. But I haven't been able to confirm that yet.

`Update`:
I ran my service via console app with a debugger attached, along with breakpoints on the function call. The UWP was successfully opened. Although a positive observation, my service is not supposed to be ran like this.

`Update 2`:
I forgot to mention that the starting process of the debug code and the production version is different. The debug code, where the UWP app was launched without issues are as follows:

```
 WindowsService service1 = new WindowsService ();
 service1.TestStartupAndStop(args); // calls this.OnStart(), sleeps for 2 secs, then calls this.OnStop()
```

My production code is simply ran by `ServiceBase`, like this:

```
ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
{
     new WindowsService ()
};
ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

Comment: Is your service allowed to interact with desktop (LogOn tab)?

Comment: I have tested above code in windows service (ms-settings:display) to launch system setting, it works well. please check if the uri is correct.

Comment: I allowed the service to interact with the desktop, but it did not work.
I also tried 'ms-settings:' and this one worked. That is strange, I may have to try calling the UWP app from other types of window apps.

Comment: I ran my service via console app with a debugger attached, along with breakpoints on the function call. The UWP was successfully opened. Although a positive observation, my service is not supposed to be ran like this. Why could this same behavior not show during normal service execution?

Comment: Have you processed [`OnActivated`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51471003/7254781) within your UWP app?

Comment: Yes, with the condition `if (e.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)`. This is being called when I call the uri from the explorer search bar.

Comment: Could you debug the uwp with un-start model?

Comment: What do you mean by `un-start model`?

Comment: Please check uwp project property->Debug-> Start action->Do not launch,but debug my code when it starts.

Comment: I tried it, and while the UWP app runs in debug mode, I ran my windows service. The breakpoint I placed within `OnActivated` function, specifically the line `if (e.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)` was not activated. 

I tried launching the app uri from explorer search bar and the breakpoint worked. This would mean that the `LaunchUriAsync` failed even though it returns success.

Comment: I have escalate this to related team, If I have received any info, I will update below

Comment: This is just a guess, but perhaps the protocol-registration for URI activation is per-user (and not per-machine)? Under which user account is your service running?

Comment: Hey there, my service is running under Local System. This should have unrestricted access to a lot of things. Do you mean to say the UWP app could possibly be limited to the user that installed it?

Comment: If you try to open some built in UWP apps from the service, will the same issue occur? And there is a similar [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92500b6d-ddcd-4b64-984d-b898c1500645/launch-uwp-app-from-windows-service-via-launchuriasync-only-works-in-debug-mode?forum=wpdevelop), you can refer to it.